# whats wrong in Details master with code in devexpress wpf dbgrid ;

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dataset, master-detail, dbgrid

I have A dataset and tow Table named t1 and t2 I need Display this Tables in Dbgrid (wpf) as master and Ditalis by Code ;

for more information please see this picture

http://www8.0zz0.com/2014/01/08/07/921573073.jpg

```
   Public Sub New()
   InitializeComponent()

   Dim Row As DataRow
   Dim ds As New DataSet1

    Row = ds.T1.NewRow
    Row("id") = 1
    Row("mname") = "AAA1"
    ds.T1.Rows.Add(Row)

    Row = ds.T1.NewRow
    Row("id") = 2
    Row("mname") = "AAA2"
    ds.T1.Rows.Add(Row)

    Row = ds.T2.NewRow
    Row("id") = 1
    Row("mname") = "AAA1"
    Row("mindex") = 1
    ds.T2.Rows.Add(Row)

    Row = ds.T2.NewRow
    Row("id") = 2
    Row("mname") = "AAA2"
    Row("mindex") = 1
    ds.T2.Rows.Add(Row)


   grid1.ItemsSource = ds.DefaultViewManager


End Sub
```

And this Wpf Tag

```
     <dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid1" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding t1}" 
                      AutoPopulateColumns="True">
        <dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
            <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding t2}">
                <dxg:GridControl 
                      ImplyNullLikeEmptyStringWhenFiltering="False" 
                       SupportDomainDataSource="False"/>
            </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor>
        </dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

My problem I dont see any data in dbgrid or how I can display master and Ditales data as this way from my dataSet by code

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Please update your questions with a detailed description of your problem.

Comment: My problem I dont see any data in dbgrid or how I can display master and Ditales data as this way from my dataSet by code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid1" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=t1}" 
                     AutoPopulateColumns="True" 
                      >

        <dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
            <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding Path= FK_t1_t2}" >
                <dxg:GridControl AutoPopulateColumns="True" >

                    </dxg:GridControl> 
            </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor>
        </dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView  NewItemRowPosition="Bottom"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>

</Grid>
```